# Jira python API add watchers

Tags: python-3.x, api, jira, jira-rest-api

im following the simple steps fro Jira ticketing documentation to add watchers to an existing issue that I created.

Im using the following section of the documentation to follow:

[add watchers](https://jira.readthedocs.io/examples.html#watchers)

however when I do that im getting the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
JIRAError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-b8833ddd08cb> in <module>
     38 jira.assign_issue(new_issue, 'mstamboulian')
     39 #jira.remove_watcher(new_issue, 'mstamboulian')
---> 40 jira.add_watcher(new_issue, 'jhutchins')
     41 
     42 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    117             else:
    118                 arg_list.append(arg)
--> 119         result = func(*arg_list, **kwargs)
    120         return result
    121 

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/client.py in add_watcher(self, issue, watcher)
   2165         """
   2166         url = self._get_url("issue/" + str(issue) + "/watchers")
-> 2167         return self._session.post(url, data=json.dumps(watcher))
   2168 
   2169     @translate_resource_args

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py in post(self, url, data, json, **kwargs)
    196 
    197     def post(self, url: Union[str, bytes], data=None, json=None, **kwargs) -> Response:  # type: ignore
--> 198         return self.__verb("POST", str(url), data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    199 
    200     def put(self, url: Union[str, bytes], data=None, **kwargs) -> Response:  # type: ignore

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py in __verb(self, verb, url, retry_data, **kwargs)
    187         if exception is not None:
    188             raise exception
--> 189         raise_on_error(response, verb=verb, **kwargs)
    190         # after raise_on_error, only Response objects are allowed through
    191         response = cast(Response, response)  # tell mypy only Response-like are here

~/programs/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jira/resilientsession.py in raise_on_error(r, verb, **kwargs)
     68             request=request,
     69             response=r,
---> 70             **kwargs,
     71         )
     72     # for debugging weird errors on CI

JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 404 url: https://guardanthealth.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/BIOD-63708/watchers
    text: {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{}}
    
    response headers = {'Date': 'Thu, 16 Jun 2022 22:23:54 GMT', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8', 'Server': 'globaledge-envoy', 'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*', 'X-Arequestid': '51664e31-86a1-4eba-b59d-6c582f68f529', 'X-Aaccountid': '5ef22eb22116eb0a7bb133a6', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, no-transform', 'Content-Encoding': 'br', 'X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time': '92', 'Expect-Ct': 'report-uri="https://web-security-reports.services.atlassian.com/expect-ct-report/atlassian-proxy", max-age=86400', 'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=63072000; preload', 'X-Content-Type-Options': 'nosniff', 'X-Xss-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'Atl-Traceid': '6e953549272756b9', 'Report-To': '{"group": "endpoint-1", "max_age": 600, "endpoints": [{"url": "https://dj9s4kmieytgz.cloudfront.net"}], "include_subdomains": true}', 'Nel': '{"report_to": "endpoint-1", "max_age": 600, "include_subdomains": true, "failure_fraction": 0.001}', 'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'}
    response text = {"errorMessages":[],"errors":{}}
```

I cannot figure out what im doing wrong, Im just invoking the following line and its throwing it off:

```
"""
Some simple authentication examples.
"""

from collections import Counter
from typing import cast

from jira import JIRA
from jira.client import ResultList
from jira.resources import Issue

user = "my_email_address"
apikey = "my_api_key"
server = "company_name.atlassian.net"


options = {
 'server': server
}

jira = JIRA(options, basic_auth=(user,apikey) )

#creating a jira issue in a specific project
#for now the project ID I want to create an issue is BIOD 
#(projects where we get the biodesk tickets assigned to)

description = """
this is a new issue created \
by JIRA API, please ignore it and \
enjoy the rest of your day"""

new_issue = jira.create_issue(project='BIOD', summary='Testing!!!!',
                              description=description,
                             issuetype={'name': 'Story'})


#assign it to whoever you want here using their username
jira.assign_issue(new_issue, 'mstamboulian')
#jira.remove_watcher(new_issue, 'mstamboulian')
jira.add_watcher(new_issue, 'mstamboulian')


watcher = jira.watchers(new_issue)
for watcher in watcher.watchers:
    print(watcher)
    # watcher is instance of jira.resources.User:
    print(watcher.emailAddress)
```

where new_issue is a jira.create_issue() that I have defined earlier which works and shows on Jira within the specified project. It is just the step where I want to add a watcher(s) that it breaks all of a sudden and I cannot figure out why. Please any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, can you share the code snippet please, in order to help you better?

Comment: @stuck thanks for your feedback I posted the whole code minus my credentials that is giving me this error, thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0):

okay actually I figured out whats going on ... you have to use the underlying user ID and not the username itself ... if I use the USER ID directly its not throwing an error but if I use the username it is throwing this error which is counter intuitive according to the docs and specially since im able to use the

```
jira.remove_watcher()
```

function using the username to remove a watcher without erroring out. Hopefully the attlassian community would fix this.